# What third-party utilities do you have in your System Preferences "Other" section?

Tags: macos, mac

I was changing something in system preferences a minute ago and stopped for a second to consider the  "Other" section and what all I had in there.  Got me wondering what other third party utilities people have gathered in their own "Other" sections.  I'll start, if you have some that you consider essential give them a mention.

[image]

- Growl for system notifications is a must have for me
- MouseWorks for the Kensington Expert Mouse gives you control over the acceleration curve (best mouse ever)
- iStat Menus for including important system info in the menubar
- Perian enables Quicktime support for a hella lot of different video formats

Comment: community wiki?

Comment: I have to admit I wasn't really sure if I should make it a wiki question or not, it doesn't really have an answer (which in my mind was partly what those are for) but not really sure how they work.

Comment: "is doesn't really have an answer" indeed is the reason why this should be CW. How they work? Just mark the checkbox next to "community wiki" when editing the question.

Comment: do you have a link for USB Overdrive?

Comment: Here you go: http://tinyurl.com/nya4fo

Answer (score 3):

[image: Flip4Mac, Growl, TextExpander, MacFuse]

TextExpander lets you type a snippet of text and replaces it with a larger snippet. I use it hundreds of times a day, for expanding code or inserting a canned response or an email signature.

I have no idea why I have MacFUSE installed. I didn't even notice it before. Guess I'll have to figure that out!

Comment: MacFUSE is for different file systems http://code.google.com/p/macfuse/

Comment: Nice, I had heard of TextExpander before and meant to check it out but never did.  Will have to grab that one

Answer (score 2):

[image: My System Preferences "Other" section]

Plaxo keeps my Address Book synced across all my computers, and for people in my Address Book who are also Plaxo members, it keeps their info updated.  The other stuff is pretty straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

Flip4Mac, Growl, MacFUSE, MySQL, Perian, SynergyKM, Xbox 360 Controllers (for playing Donkey Kong in MAME)

Answer (score 0):

Little Snitch is on my "others"